# Убрать из списка спецсимволы, которые не в центре

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Есть список:

```
['Новая', 'винтовка', '«Койот»!', '', 'Друзья,', 'оружейник', 'не', 'спит.', 'В', 'скором', 'времени', 'у', 'вас', 'появится', 'отличная', 'возможность', 'пострелять', 'из', 'новой', 'пушки.', 'Поскольку', 'винтовка', 'Мосина', 'была', 'сдвинута', 'с', '13', 'на', '16', 'уровень,', 'охотникам', 'требуется', 'новое', 'оружие,', 'доступное', 'на', '13-ом', 'уровне.', 'Место', '"Мосинки"', 'на', '13-ом', 'уровне', 'займет', 'винтовка', '"Койот",', 'которая', 'будет', 'использовать', 'калибр', '5.45.', 'Винтовка', 'будет', 'доступна', 'с', 'обновлением', '0.48.', '☝', '', '', '', 'Характеристики', '"Койота":', '•', 'Калибр:', '5.45х39', '•', 'Урон', 'винтовки', '(min-max):', '250-325', '', '•', 'Урон', 'патрона', '(min-max):', '60-140', '', '•', 'Общий', 'урон', '(min-max):', '310-465', '', '•', 'Бронебойность', 'патрона:', '15-25', '', '•', 'Бронебойность', 'оружия:', '5-10', '', '•', 'Кучность:', '1', 'MOA', '', '•', 'Вес:', '3.8', 'кг']
```

Необходимо убрать все спецсимволы, если они стоят не в центре

Comment: добавьте к списку ожидаемый результат

Comment: что значит в "центре"? Какой результат для `['.']`. Что вы к "спецсимволам" относите?

Comment: К спецсимволам я отношу все, кроме букв. Под "в центре", я понимаю, от первого кириллического слева до крайнего кириллического символа справа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать регуляркой исключить все символы, что не совпадают с перечисленными:

```
import re

def my_strip(text):
    text = re.sub('^[^а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9a-zA-Z]+', '', text)
    text = re.sub('[^а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9a-zA-Z]+$', '', text)
    return text

items = ['Новая', 'винтовка', '«Койот»!', '', 'Друзья,', 'оружейник', 'не', 'спит.', 'В', 'скором', 'времени', 'у', 'вас', 'появится', 'отличная', 'возможность', 'пострелять', 'из', 'новой', 'пушки.', 'Поскольку', 'винтовка', 'Мосина', 'была', 'сдвинута', 'с', '13', 'на', '16', 'уровень,', 'охотникам', 'требуется', 'новое', 'оружие,', 'доступное', 'на', '13-ом', 'уровне.', 'Место', '"Мосинки"', 'на', '13-ом', 'уровне', 'займет', 'винтовка', '"Койот",', 'которая', 'будет', 'использовать', 'калибр', '5.45.', 'Винтовка', 'будет', 'доступна', 'с', 'обновлением', '0.48.', '☝', '', '', '', 'Характеристики', '"Койота":', '•', 'Калибр:', '5.45х39', '•', 'Урон', 'винтовки', '(min-max):', '250-325', '', '•', 'Урон', 'патрона', '(min-max):', '60-140', '', '•', 'Общий', 'урон', '(min-max):', '310-465', '', '•', 'Бронебойность', 'патрона:', '15-25', '', '•', 'Бронебойность', 'оружия:', '5-10', '', '•', 'Кучность:', '1', 'MOA', '', '•', 'Вес:', '3.8', 'кг']
print([my_strip(x) for x in items])
```

Результат:

```
['Новая', 'винтовка', 'Койот', '', 'Друзья', 'оружейник', 'не', 'спит', 'В', 'скором', 'времени', 'у', 'вас', 'появится', 'отличная', 'возможность', 'пострелять', 'из', 'новой', 'пушки', 'Поскольку', 'винтовка', 'Мосина', 'была', 'сдвинута', 'с', '13', 'на', '16', 'уровень', 'охотникам', 'требуется', 'новое', 'оружие', 'доступное', 'на', '13-ом', 'уровне', 'Место', 'Мосинки', 'на', '13-ом', 'уровне', 'займет', 'винтовка', 'Койот', 'которая', 'будет', 'использовать', 'калибр', '5.45', 'Винтовка', 'будет', 'доступна', 'с', 'обновлением', '0.48', '', '', '', '', 'Характеристики', 'Койота', '', 'Калибр', '5.45х39', '', 'Урон', 'винтовки', 'min-max', '250-325', '', '', 'Урон', 'патрона', 'min-max', '60-140', '', '', 'Общий', 'урон', 'min-max', '310-465', '', '', 'Бронебойность', 'патрона', '15-25', '', '', 'Бронебойность', 'оружия', '5-10', '', '', 'Кучность', '1', 'MOA', '', '', 'Вес', '3.8', 'кг']
```

---

Либо через функцию `strip` описать какие символы нужно убрать.

Пример:

```
print('«Койот»!'.strip('«»!'))  # Койот
```

Код выше стал бы, примерно такой. Вам только нужно больше спецсимволов описать:

```
print([x.strip('«»!') for x in items])
```

Comment: Точка в "5.45." не по центру, а осталась.

Comment: В результате, в ответе ее (точки) нет. Откуда вы ее взяли?

Comment: Второй нет, первая осталась. И в "0.48" тоже.

Comment: Я как понял из вопроса, автор не имел ввиду прямо в центре, а хотел чтобы с обеих сторон были удалены спецсимволы. Впрочем, я попросил результат как он его видит, останется его дождаться. Еще вы можете у автора уточнить этот вопрос

Comment: Если так интерпретировать, то да. Пожалуй, даже более правильная интерпретация.

Comment: Приношу извинения, что меня долго не было. Я хотел, чтоб, спецсимволы были удалены только по краям. Внутри удалять ничего не нужно. Так, как 5.45, 7.62 - это калибры. Точка тут важна. Например что-либо. Тире тут тоже нужно оставить, а вот есть "калибр.". Очевидно, что тут точка лишняя